# не меняется язык vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Выбираю через ctl+shift+p вкладку >Configure Display Language, далее установленный пакет языка RU. VSCode предлагает перезапуск, **перезапускаю программу** но язык интерфейса остаётся прежним. Надеюсь у вас есть идеи как это можно решить.[image: Выбор языка в программе VSCode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь Вам поможет только переустановка программы.
Я же убрал галочку **только чтение** у папки `C:\Users\UserName\AppData`
Так же очистил реестр windows. Возможно эти 3 шага необходимы чтобы точно починить ваш VSCode :)